# Тело вопроса не отвечает стандартам качества проекта

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

> Тело вопроса не отвечает стандартам качества проекта. Убедитесь, что в нем полностью описана проблема, а также Ваши решения, в грамматически правильной форме.

И где эти стандарты качества? Я вот не понимаю, что от меня хочет система и надо исправлять. Вопрос на мете.

---

Так, на этот вопрос тоже. Ну и что с ним делать?

Comment: Ага, как обходить валидацию я понял...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если текст вопроса короткий — дублируем его несколько раз, проходим валидацию, а затем жмём на правку и удаляем дубликаты.

Comment: Ага, я до этого и догадался :)

Comment: Всё для людей, однако.

Answer (score 11):

По-моему, фильтр в том числе срабатывает, если сообщение слишком короткое. Блесните великим и могучим русским языком: пишите витиеватыми выражениями, растекайтесь мыслью по древу...

Или просто включите в ваше сообщение больше информации. Тоже помогает.

Comment: Для коротких в других местах вроде так и пишется, что надо столько-то символов. Чего же тут сообщение не такое?

Comment: @Qwertiy У меня на мете тоже один раз сработал фильтр. Я добавил текста и оно заткнулось. Так как больше не проявлялось, то я забил.

Comment: Ограничение по количеству символов тоже есть (не менее 30). Но "стандарты качества" также учитывают другие аспекты: например, состоит ли вопрос из кода без всякого пояснения, и т.п.

Comment: @Yes, конкретно этот вопрос в том виде, в каком он сейчас, чем не соответствует?

Comment: @Qwertiy Цитатой, например? Предполагается, что цитируемый текст берётся извне, то есть текста от собственно автора мало.

Comment: Ну явно больше озвученных 30 символов.

Comment: У меня такое было не раз, в вопросах по меткам. Я просто добавлял метки не именами, а именно разметкой - тогда принимало. Движок видимо хочет, чтобы использовали его возможности, иначе обижается и не пускает.