# Непонятные сообщения системы для слишком короткого заголовка и текста

Tags: предложение, вопросы

Только что писал вопрос. У него был достаточно короткий заголовок и текст, [как в этой редакции](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/549/2). Вопрос не принимался, пришлось [дописать бессмысленных слов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/549/1) в заголовок и тело вопроса. Тогда получилось опубликовать.

Вот, кстати, очень похожий вопрос: [Тело вопроса не отвечает стандартам качества проекта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276/181472)

Вижу проблему в том, что показанные сообщения не объясняют, в чем, собственно проблема. Она была не в осмысленности и не в грамматике, а просто в количестве символов. А об этом сообщение как раз не говорит.

Хотелось бы знать, по какой именно причине заголовок или вопрос не принимаются в текущей редакции.

Может быть, как с созданием метки сделать? Посмотрел на предупреждение, нажал кнопку `Да, я уверен в том, что я делаю`... Сомневаюсь, впрочем, что такое изменение движка возможно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне помогало использование всяких тегов(я добавил метку в вопрос, и его сразу приняло). Метку в тело вопроса, а не в список меток

Comment: гипотеза: может быть, парсером оценивается (в том числе) количество **латинских** букв, цифр и спец-символов (скобок и т.п.), а количество кириллицы либо вообще не учитывается, либо влияет с меньшим «весом»?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: вряд ли. Есть не-программистские сайты на других языках, например про ислам. Там вообще во многих вопросах ни одной буквы латиницы.

Answer (score 4):

Можно как-нибудь так. С явным предложением написать больше букв и цифр.

> Заголовок слишком короткий. Возможно, он недостаточно точно обозначает предмет вопроса. Пожалуйста, дополните его и убедитесь, что он сформулирован ясно и грамматически правильно.

(Часть про подробное описание проблемы я убрал, это вроде бы очевидно).

> Тело вопроса слишком короткое. Возможно, оно недостаточно полно раскрывает предмет вопроса. Пожалуйста, дополните его и убедитесь, что в нём полностью описана проблема, а также ваши решения, в грамматически правильной форме.