# Почему у меня требует вводить так много текста на англоязычном Stack Overflow?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что мне делать? Я описал все что мог, оно все равно не работает

Comment: Слабовато описали. Можно было как минимум описать ожидание/реальность.

Comment: Зарубежный SO он такой, русским покоя не дает, а в чем проблема задать сие вопрос у нас? Или вы не знаете русский?

Comment: По react native вопрос. На русском практически никто никогда не отвечает

Comment: Одно-единственное предложение "Why animation does not work?" это все что мог? Это совсем не описание, это "ничего не смог описать". Правильно, что не работает. За такое "описание" все равно заминусуют и удалят. И правильно сделают.

Comment: Там выше описания гораздо больше

Comment: Что значит "Why animation does not work"? Вообще не работает? Работает, но не так как ожидаешь?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy там другое. Придумали какую-то странную проверку на процент кода в вопросе, если он больше определенного значения, не дает отправить. И трюк с правкой не помогает, насколько я знаю.

Comment: "Там выше описания гораздо больше" - если там выше гораздо больше описания, то его надо вынести из кода. Под полем ввода есть превью сообщения и оно состоит из одной-единственной строчки. Это означает, что весь остальной текст - код. О чем вам и написано.

Answer (score 4):

### Валидация

На мой взгляд, эта валидация, которая сработала очень даже уместна. Вы же программист, оставьте безликие и некомпетентные фразы "оно не работает" начинающим пользователям.

### Где вы?

Самое главное, чтобы вы понимали, что вы на сайте вопросов-ответов, где ваш вопрос должен быть потенциально интересен другим людям, которые приходят сюда с поисковиков. Сверхидея сайта — база знаний. Безликие формулировки "оно не работает" никак не наполняют данную базу знаний.

### Больше деталей для понимания и вопроизведения вашей проблемы.

Расскажите подробней, что для вас "не работает". Если это ошибка компиляции, исполнения, то приведите её код. Если это работает без ошибок, то опишите, что получается некий результат А, а вы хотите результат Б. Добавьте, если уместно, картинку, но крайне важно это в первую очередь точно описать текстом, так как ищут люди ищут проблемы просто вбивая текст в поисковики, а не с помощью изображений.

Но при этом помните, что деталей надо минимально, чтобы просто понять и воспроизвести вашу проблему. Код всей программы, если она много тысяч строк приводить не стоит почти в 100% случаев. Иначе ваш вопрос становится слишком общим и это больше похоже на бесплатную работу за вас.

### Что вы пробовали?

Очень хорошо, чтобы вы также уточняли о том, что вы до этого пробовали. Я не считаю, что это в 100% случаев обязательно и уместно делать, но в большинстве случаев это подходит для того чтобы

- данное решение вам не предлагалось,
- упростить поиск решений для тех кто хочет вам помочь, чтобы не терять время на то, что вы уже пробовали. Если ваша задача требует для решения много разных шагов и путь для решения крайне далёк, то вероятность качественного ответа невысока. Максимально облегчите путь тем, кто будет пробовать пройти дальше вас в решении данной задачи.
- чтобы продемонстрировать желание решить проблему, а не спихивать ответственность на окружающих, желая бесплатно сделать за кого-то работу (для многих пользователей это важно).

Comment: Я же написал. что текста выше гораздо больше. Ну можно прочитать прежде чем писать "оно не работает"

Comment: @sinevik Почему вы тогда не написали весь текст поста прям здесь? Почему только скрин небольшого фрагмента? Так же лучше было бы вопроизвести и решить вашу проблему. Возможно также можно было бы улучшить вопрос. Также неясно  соответствует ли ваш вопрос [MCVE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).